# React this.setState doesnt rerender content

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing simple application which need to rerender specified content.

My ideas about resolving the issue was to provide initializing data in constructor because something breaks react structure?But maybe helpful might be a tip how to map two dimensional  array in render method. Propably here is the problem?

```
function Pool(props) {
        return(     
            <p className={`${props.row}`}></p>      
        );
}


export default class Board extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            mainArray: [],
         };
    }


    createBoard() {
    let children=[];
    let array=[];
        for(let i=0;i<20;i++){
            children=[];
            for(let j=0;j<20;j++){
                children.push(<Pool key={`${i}${j}`} row={`${square1}`}/>);
            }   
        array.push(<div key={`${i}`}>{children}</div>);     
        }
    this.state.mainArray=array;
    return this.state.mainArray;
    }

    startGame = () => {
        let array1=[];
        array1=this.state.mainArray.slice;
        let i=6;
        for(let j in array1[6]){
            array1[6][j]=<Pool key={`${i}${j}`} row={`${square2}`}/>;
        }
        this.setState({mainArray: array1});

    }


    render() {
        return (        
            <div  className="main"> 
            {this.createBoard()}
            <button onClick={this.startGame}>Start the game!</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I am trying to change the colour of the sixth row for example.Regards

Comment: It's basically a typo, `array1=this.state.mainArray.slice;` should be `array1=this.state.mainArray.slice();` (and you don't need `=[]` on the previous line).

Comment: let array1=this.state.mainArray.slice();
And this line outputs the same:   array1[6][j]=<Pool key={`${i}${j}`} row={`${square2}`}/>;

Comment: You're also breaking one of the fundamental React rules here: `this.state.mainArray=array;`. Never modify state directly. I suggest working through some basic React tutorials.

Comment: this one doesn't break reactjs rules:   render and the way I am rendering  in line
 "{this.createBoard()}" ?? or it should be in constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
        let array1=[];
        array1=this.state.mainArray.slice;
```

`mainArray.slice()` is a copy, but `mainArray.slice` is a *function*. 
Instead, begin with

```
        let array1 = this.state.mainArray.slice();
```

Comment: I am getting Cannot assign to read only property '$$typeof' of object '#<Object>' in line "array1[6][j]=<Pool key={`${i}${j}`} row={`${square2}`}/>;"